# VBA Shapes.AddTextbox Method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Shapes.AddTextbox Method() in my code, in particular in a given condition I add a new text box and then I delete it. The problem is, when the textbox is created I receive a messagebox from Excel that shows the number of the text box created, then I have to click on the "OK" button of the message box in order to close it and continue running the code.
I there a way to avoid this message box appears?

thanks !
regards

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to ans if you can provide your code.

By the way please see the below example so that you can get the idea how add a text box in your excel file.

```
 Sub DrawTextbox()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Create label (height/width will be set by AutoSize).
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 100, 100)
    s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "This is some label text"
    ' Resize text box to fit text.
    s.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
end sub
```

Comment: This answer gave me just enough information to figure out how to work with TextBoxes. If you need to use the same TextBox later, you can name it, e.g. `s.Name = "mybox"`. Later, when you need to use it again, do something like `Set s = ws.Shapes("mybox")`.