# TextBox object customisation - Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a textbox like this in my Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

I used this query: [VBA Shapes.AddTextbox Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480211/vba-shapes-addtextbox-method)

I modified the code:

```
Sub asbuiltstamp()
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
 800, 50, 200, 75) _
.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "City Fibre As-Built"
.Font.ColorIndex = 3
.Font.Size = 20
.Font.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.Shapes.Rotation = 45
.Shapes.Fill = False

End Sub
```

I get:

> Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference.

[image]

How can I customise my textbox with VBA Excel?
How can I set its own name (other than "Textbox1")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried to access several properties without specifying what they are properties of. You need something like this:

```
Sub asbuiltstamp()
   Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
   With myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 800, 50, 200, 75)
      With .TextFrame
         .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
         With .Characters
        .Text = "City Fibre" & vbLf & "As-Built"
        With .Font
           .Bold = True
           .ColorIndex = 3
           .Size = 20
        End With
         End With
      End With
      .Rotation = 45
      .Fill.Visible = False
   End With

End Sub
```