# Copy the element throughout a whole workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Continuing the question:
[TextBox object customisation - Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322722/textbox-object-customisation-compile-error-invalid-or-unqualified-reference)

I am going to copy this element - textbox into all worksheets throughout my document.
I would like to have it exactly in the same place in each worksheet.

For this purpose I used the code:

```
 Sub Asbuildcopy()
 Dim wsh As Worksheet
 Dim ArraySheets As String
 Dim x As Variant


 For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 3").Copy
 Application.Goto Sheets(ArraySheets).Range("Q6")
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 ArraySheets(x) = wsh.Name
        x = x + 1

End Sub
```

According to the advice here:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/73851-copy-shape-to-cell-on-another-worksheet/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOhJj.png

stating about copying an element into another sheet.

Apart from my code, one problem is the location of this element. I used target cell as Q6, but I would like to have it exactly in the same place as on the 1st (initial) sheet.

Thank you for your hint,

Comment: Don't use `activesheet` as that is changed by your code. You can use the property of a shape - top, left.

Comment: I don't see the point of `ArraySheets` here, plus `ArraySheets(x) = wsh.Name` is problematic given `Dim ArraySheets As String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. As per comment, can use the `Top` and `Left` properties of a shape to position it as per the first sheet.

Use more meaningful procedure and variable names for your actual code.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, s As Shape

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")      'sheet containing original textbox
Set s = ws1.Shapes("TextBox 3")     'name of original textbox

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
        s.Copy
        ws.Paste
        ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).Top = s.Top    
        ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).Left = s.Left
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly use `Shapes.Count` to index? Untested.