# Remove the element throughout the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Continuing the previous query:

[Copy the element throughout a whole workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325578/copy-the-element-throughout-a-whole-workbook)

I would like to have my shape removed.

In this purpose I used the following code:

```
     Sub asbuilremove()
        Dim shp As Shape, sh As Worksheet
        Set ass = sh.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
           For Each shp In sh.Shapes
              ass.Delete
           Next
        Next
     End Sub
```

As per the example here:

https://officetricks.com/vba-macro-delete-shapes-excel-workbook-objects-boxes/

But I am getting the error:
**Runtime error 5
Invalid procedure call or argument**

How can I remove my previously created texbox(object) then?

[image]

Comment: In which line do you get the error? And why is there `Set ass = Shapes("AsBuiltBox")` if it is not used?

Comment: I set now ass.delete, but I am still getting the same

Comment: What *sheet* is `Shapes("AsBuiltBox")` on?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. `For Each shp In sh.Shapes` loops through all shapes in the sheet `sh` and therefore the code shown deletes *all* shapes in *all* sheets. Also you did not answer my question in which code line you get the error?

Comment: This is the line:
Set ass = Shapes("AsBuiltBox")

Comment: `Set ass = sh.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")`.

Comment: Now you've got the order mixed up. You can't use `sh` before `For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets`.

Comment: I have updated my code, so see as it stands now. I am getting error:
Object variable or With variable not set

Comment: See my last comment, you're trying to use `sh` too early. Excel only knows what `sh` is from the line `For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheet`, which is *after* `Set ass = sh.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim shp As Shape, sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets
    On Error Resume Next 'disable error reporting (next line will throw an error if AsBuiltBox does not exist)
    Set shp = sh.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-enable error reporting

    'if AsBuiltBox exists delete it
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next sh
```

It will delete a shape named `AsBuiltBox` on all worksheets (if it exists).